# Eclipse Spring 404 while navigating jsp

Tags: eclipse, spring, maven

After importing working maven project to Eclipse Neon while running on Tomcat v9 there was 404 error. I partly resolved it when added every folder containing .jsp files to Web Deployment Assembly property in project properties. Also i added controller and configuration folders. Now when i click every page separately they work in browser but when navigating links still give 404 not found error.

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan("com.resman.*")
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class AppConfig {

    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("/resources/**").addResourceLocations("/resources/");
    }

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("/WEB-INF/view/jsp/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return viewResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationDAO applicationDAO() {
        return new ApplicationDAOImpl(dataSource());
    }

    @Bean
    public ResourceDao resourceDao() {
        return new ResourceDaoImpl(dataSource());}

}
```

Index controller

```
@Controller
public class IndexController {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String index(Model model) {
        return "index/index";
    }

}
```

User Controller

```
@Controller
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    private UserDao userDao;

    @RequestMapping(value = "create-user-form", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String createUserForm() {
        return "user/create";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "create", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String create(HttpServletRequest request) {
        UserRole userRole = new UserRole((long) Roles.APPLICANT.getId(), "Applicant");
        BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder = new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
        String hashedPassword = bCryptPasswordEncoder.encode(request.getParameter("password"));

        User newUSer = new User
                .UserBuilder(request.getParameter("firstName"), request.getParameter("lastName"),
                request.getParameter("email"), hashedPassword)
                .phoneNumber(request.getParameter("phoneNumber")).build();

        userDao.createUser(newUSer, userRole);

        return "redirect:/all-users";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "all-users", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String findAll(Model model) {
        List<User> userList = userDao.findAll();
        model.addAttribute("userList", userList);

        return "user/allUsers";
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "remove-user/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String remove(@PathVariable Long id) {
        User user = userDao.findUserById(id);
        userDao.removeUser(user);

        return "user/removeUserNotification";
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "profile/{id}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String findProfile(@PathVariable Long id, Model model) {
        User user = userDao.findUserById(id);
        model.addAttribute("user", user);

        return "user/profile";
    }

    @RequestMapping(path = "edit-profile/{id}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String editProfile(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestParam String lastName, @RequestParam String phoneNumber) {
        return "redirect:/profile/" + id;
    }

}
```

web.xml

```
<web-app id="resourceManager" version="2.4"
         xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee
 http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
</web-app>
```

project structure

[image: project structure]

[image: web deployment assembly]

Unfortunatelly I cannot modify the project/ project structure itself to make it work, the only way is via editing Eclipse or Tomcat properties. On IntelliJ + Tomcat v9 everything worked fine

Comment: One advice. Strart using Spring Boot... It will solve most of your problems :)

Comment: Try this **return "index"** instead of this  **return "index/index";**